# How do I derive the frequency of an LFO circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, oscillator, multisim, schmitt-trigger

I'm attempting to solve why the frequency of an LFO, which is a Schmitt Trigger - Integrator LFO, seems to be about 7.13 Hz even when the reverse logarithmic potentiometer is set to its lowest setting. I've scoured the web for any sort of an answer and the only clue I found was in a forum where someone suggested finding out which resistor/s were responsible for charging the capacitor and to then solve for  (tau.) From there f = 1/2pi(). Except after multiple equations with varying resistors in parallel, the highest resistance I was able to solve for was 455k ohms. For a capacitance of 10nF and a frequency of 7.13 Hz, I'd need a resistance of 2.228M ohms.

Consulting a book like Sergio Franco's Design with Operational Amplifiers and Analog Integrated Circuits, I feel a bit out of my league. Also, in the Schmitt-Trigger section I can only find equations for VTH and VTL that lead me nowhere after plugging in the values and solving them.

Here's the oscilloscope reading from the circuit in Multisim, which is how I figured it had a frequency of approximately 7.13 Hz:

[image: Oscilloscope Reading]

Here we have the LFO circuit in question:

[image: LFO Circuit Schmitt Trigger - Integrator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of voltages off-schematic here, \$V_{BIAS}\$ and \$V_{REF}\$, which will both affect duty cycle and frequency, and it's going to be hard to produce an expression for frequency in terms of them all. I'll ignore them for now.

C10 and R17 have a time constant way shorter than that of the timing elements formed by C9, RV1 and R16, leading me to believe that their role is not so much to control timing, more likely to provide strong negative feedback at high frequency, to limit output slew rate. In any case the dominant elements in control of timing are C9, RV1 and R16.

With RV1 set to 0Ω, the time constant becomes

$$ \tau = C_9 \times (RV_1 + R_{16}) = 10\mu F \times (0\Omega + 4.7k\Omega ) \approx 50ms $$

Given that this time constant is the time it takes a capacitor to charge to about 63% of its "final" or "target" voltage, and that R18 and R19 are setting that target to a similar fraction of the entire voltage range, right off the bat we can estimate frequency. Charging will take roughly one time constant, discharging the same, for a total oscillation period of about \$50ms + 50ms= 100ms\$, and a frequency of about 10Hz. More precisely, though, we can calculate it as follows.

The maximum and minimum op-amp output potentials are \$V_{MAX}\$ and \$V_{MIN}\$. With \$V_{REF} = 0V\$, the two switching thresholds are half of those values, due to the potential divider R18 and R19. The upper and lower thresholds are \$V_{UPPER} = \frac{V_{MAX}}{2}\$ and \$V_{LOWER}=\frac{V_{MIN}}{2}\$.

How long does it take C9 (initially charged to \$V_{LOWER}\$), to charge up to \$V_{UPPER}\$, given a "target" potential of \$V_{MAX}\$? The situation looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwwHrE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor is initially charged so that the potential at node X is \$V_X = V_{MIN} = -10V\$. At time \$t=0\$ we flip the switch, and C1 charges towards \$V_X = V_{MAX} = +10V\$. We want to know the times when \$V_X = V_{LOWER}\$ and \$V_X = V_{UPPER}\$. The resulting graph of \$V_X\$ against time:

[image]

The equation for the voltage across an initially discharged capacitor \$C\$ charging up via resistance \$R\$, given some potential *difference* \$V_{S}\$ across the \$RC\$ pair is:

$$ V_X = V_S\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right) $$

where

$$ \tau = RC $$

There are a few ways of adapting this to our situation, but I think in this case the most intuitive approach is to realise this: we could offset all potentials in the circuit by +100V, -50V, or *any* amount, effectively shifting the graph upwards or downwards, but it wouldn't change the *shape* of that curve, or the time constant, in any way. The potential *differences* would all remain the same.

This means that while the above equation assumes the capacitor is initially discharged, and in our case it's *starting* charged to \$V_{LOWER}=-5V\$. Imagine all values shifted up by +5V, so it seems as if the capacitor is discharged (0V across it). The time it takes to go between \$V_{LOWER}\$ and \$V_{UPPER}\$, the interval between the green markers in the graph, wouldn't change at all.

In our case:

$$ \tau = 4.7k\Omega \times 10\mu F = 47ms $$

The voltage \$V_S\$ across the RC pair will be the difference \$V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}\$, and all potentials are offset by amount \$V_{MIN}\$. Adapting the equation above:

$$ V_X = V_{MIN}+(V_{MAX}-V_{MIN})\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right) $$

We need to solve for time \$t\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} &= \frac{V_X-V_{MIN}}{V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}}-1 \\ \\
-\frac{t}{\tau } &= ln\left(1 - \frac{V_X-V_{MIN}}{V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}}\right) \\ \\
t &= \tau \cdot ln\left(\frac{V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}}{V_{MAX}-V_X}\right) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

There are two instants in time of interest, where \$V_X\$ passes through the thresholds, \$V_X=V_{LOWER}\$ and \$V_X=V_{UPPER}\$. Plugging those in:

$$
\begin{aligned}
t_{LOWER} &= \tau \cdot ln\left(\frac{V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}}{V_{MAX}-V_{LOWER}}\right) \\ \\
&= 47ms \cdot ln\left(\frac{(+10V)-(-10V)}{(+10V)-(-5V)}\right) \\ \\
&= 13.5ms
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
t_{UPPER} &= \tau \cdot ln\left(\frac{V_{MAX}-V_{MIN}}{V_{MAX}-V_{UPPER}}\right) \\ \\
&= 47ms \cdot ln\left(\frac{(+10V)-(-10V)}{(+10V)-(+5V)}\right) \\ \\
&= 65.2ms
\end{aligned}
$$

As you can see, these values for \$t\$ correspond to the simulated instants where \$V_X\$ crosses the lower and upper thresholds in the graph above.

The time between them represents the period when the op-amp output is high, causing the capacitor to charge:

$$ T_{HIGH} = t_{UPPER} - t_{LOWER} = 65.2ms - 13.5ms = 51.7ms $$

When the upper threshold is reached, the op-amp output goes low, entering a phase where the capacitor discharges. The situation becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzICnJ.png)</sup>

[image]

If you look closely, the times when \$V_X\$ crosses the thresholds are identical to the charging cycle. This is due to the symmetry of the system, between \$V_{MAX}\$, \$V_{MIN}\$, \$V_{UPPER}\$ and \$V_{LOWER}\$. This symmetry would be broken if \$V_{REF}\ne 0\$. For such a condition, you'd have different, asymmetric values for \$V_{LOWER}\$ and \$V_{UPPER}\$.

During discharge, the classic RC discharge equation is:

$$ V_X = V_Se^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} $$

For our case we would have:

$$ V_X = V_{MIN}+(V_{MAX}-V_{MIN})e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} $$

I'll leave you to rearrange that to obtain an expression for \$t\$. For me I'm going to assume, by symmetry, that

$$ T_{LOW} = T_{HIGH} = 51.7ms $$

The total period \$T\$ of the entire cycle is:

$$ T = T_{LOW} + T_{HIGH} = 103ms $$

That corresponds to this frequency:

$$ f = \frac{1}{T} = 9.7Hz $$

This is the highest frequency of oscillation you can expect with \$V_{REF}=0V\$, since increasing RV1 will increase \$\tau\$.

Earlier I noted that R18 and R19 produced thresholds near 50%, which is true but misleading. From the charge curve above, it's clear that the "distance" between starting potential \$V_X=V_{LOWER}\$ and target potential \$V_X=V_{MAX}\$ is 15V. Similarly, during discharge the difference is \$V_{UPPER}-V_{MIN}=15V\$. In each half cycle, \$V_X\$ must traverse \$V_{UPPER}-V_{LOWER}=(+5V)-(-5V)=10V\$. As a fraction that's \$\frac{10}{15}=67\%\$.

I also said that *one time constant* is how long it takes to traverse 63% of the remaining distance. That's close to 67%, which is why original frequency estimate was so good, at 100Hz.

It would have been more *useful* say that R18 and R19 produce thresholds that require capacitor voltage to traverse about 67% of the remaining difference between long-term end state +10V, and initial state -5V.

Going back to my point about C10 and R17, and how they slow the rising and falling of the output, this will obviously have some effect. Their time constant is \$150k\Omega \times 10nF = 1.5ms\$. While it's difficult to do the math that will account for their influence, it's a reasonable guess that they could introduce an extra 1.5ms at each transition, for a total of 3ms on top of our calculated 103ms period.

From the asymmetry visible in your own graph, where duty cycle is very far from 50%, this would suggest that \$V_{REF}\$ is significantly non-zero, and might very well contribute to the notable discrepancy between my theoretical frequency calculation and your own measured frequency of 7.1Hz. Also, I don't know what you have \$V_{BIAS}\$ set to.

Comment: This is a far more comprehensive answer than I was expecting, which I am very grateful for! My apologies for Vref and VBias not being included, I thought I had included Vref but it seems I deleted it mistakenly during an edit. In any case, it's 5.1 V as provided by a zener diode. VBias is being applied to a JFET's gate, controlling it as a variable resistor. The J113s I have, VBias should range from 1.6 to 3.8 V (I went with 3.8 V). I appreciate both the rough approximation as well as the thorough analysis. Do you have a book you could recommend for better understanding op amp design?

Comment: @Thxforhelping I wish I could remember the books I used while studying, but that was thirty-something years ago, I'm not even sure I still have them. My main go-to book since then has always been "The Art of Electronics" by Horowitz and Hill, which has a quite comprehensive op-amp section.